# oke ddaas banj aj

Tags: sql

If you want to remove an item from an array, you can use the pop() method to remove the last element or the shift() method to remove the first element.

However, if the item you want to remove is not the first or last element, these methods are not the tools for the job.

The Solution
There are a few methods you can use to remove specific elements from an array in JavaScript. If the pop() or shift() methods won’t work for your purposes, you can select a method depending on whether you’ll identify the item by its value or its index.

Removing the Last Element of an Array
The pop() method removes and returns the last element of an array.

const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const x = myArray.pop();

console.log(`myArray values: ${myArray}`);
console.log(`variable x value: ${x}`);

Output:

myArray values: 1,2,3,4
variable x value: 5
Removing the First Element of an Array
The shift() method removes and returns the first element of an array.

const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const x = myArray.shift();

console.log(`myArray values: ${myArray}`);
console.log(`variable x value: ${x}`);
Output:

myArray values = 2,3,4,5
variable x value: 1
Removing an Element by Index
If you are identifying the item to be removed by its index, you can use the delete operator. If you want to use the value of the item you are removing, use the splice() method.

The delete Operator
The delete operator deletes the object property at the specified index, but does not update the length of the array, and the value at that index of the array will be undefined.

const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

delete myArray[1];

console.log(`myArray values: ${myArray}`);
Output:

myArray values: 1,,3,4,5
The splice() Method
The splice() method takes two arguments, the index of the element you wish to remove and the index you wish to remove up to.

The splice() method creates a new array that stores all the values that were removed from the original array. The original array will no longer contain the values removed, and its length will be updated.